# Dynamics CRM: write from Excel to CRM

Tags: excel, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, vba

I have the following customer scenario:

User clicks on button in Excel and data from certain Excel-Sheet is transferred to Dynamics CRM.

Someone ever did something like this? Possible with VBA or JavaScript?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box CRM provides the ability to import Excel spreadsheets to create or update existing records.

Or you can always build something custom, manipulating CRM data via the web services.

Comment: Hey James, thx for ur reply. But I m wondering how to use the web service via VBA. Cant find any good resource in the internet. Did u ever do something like this?

Comment: @Alanovic, not myself, Excel to CRM integration are little esoteric.

Answer (score 0):

I have done somewhat similar thing with excel, except i wrote vsto addin that used bit modern approach. You can easily use crm sdk ddl when writing add-ins for excel.

But with VBA i think you might hit quite wall there, you would have to write almost all methods over.

My prefer for here would be write vba script that send excel sheet data to webserver (node.js, .net) and there you can make actual data transfer to crm api. One good example would be writing csv file from data and save it to server, trigger server to manipulate that data.